# how can an administrator user delete files

Tags: permissions, administrator

i have 2 different profiles / users created on my ubuntu box.  both are admins.  but when i'm using the gui and i try to delete files, or move files it doesn't look like i have permissions to do so.  I can't save files that I've created using sublime text editor either. 
Can you tell me what I'm missing? 
is there a way around this or do i always have to use the terminal window with the sudo command?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Nautilus in gksudo mode. Bring up a terminal and type:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

brings up the file browser in sudo mode.

Comment: i did that. and then i right clicked inside the folder where i want to create a new file and selected "create new document -> empty document".  i created a file called "default.html". then i tried to edit that file by dragging it in to sublime.  but i still can't save it.

Comment: i figured it out. i had to start sublime editor from nautilus. and then it works.

Comment: i think 'gksudo sublime' from terminal should also work.